# Is there a reverse Clickjacking, from a rogue iframe to the parent embedding it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, clickjacking

The `X-Frame-Options: DENY` is a hammer way for websites to prevent others from embedding themselves into an `iframe`, making it impossible to do an attack known as "Clickjacking".

However, other than merely killing the web, the `X-Frame-Options` is explicitly rather useless in other scenarios.

What if I'm the one doing the embedding of an untrusted source in an iframe on my site?  And I place such untrusted source within an `iframe`, can such an iframe make direct harm to my own visual elements?

Below is a simplified example of what I'm talking about:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>blah</title>
<style type='text/css'>
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    header {
        /* can example.com/untrusted break into this? */
        z-index:    1;
        position:   absolute;
        background-color:   rgba(224, 224, 224, 0.8);
        padding: 2em;
    }
    iframe {
        /* out of this? */
        position:   absolute;
        border: 0;
        width:  100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <header>
    <a href="/trusted/confirm-purchase">buy this immediately!</a>
    </header>
<iframe
    src='http://example.com/untrusted'
    width='800' height='480'
    seamless='seamless'
>
</iframe>
</body>
```

Am I all good, or can the operator of http://example.com/untrusted form a successful attack vector on my page?  Is there anything to look for?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the iframe [**sandboxing**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) feature

Comment: @Bergi, oh, cool!  So, I should just add an empty `sandbox` attribute?  Or one containing "allow-scripts", if I am to embed any sort of a modern web-site that wouldn't work without javascript?

Comment: I think so, yes. But don't trust the `sandbox` attribute completely, it's not supported in some browsers. You should always make sure that cross-domain security applies

Comment: so, that's what i'm asking -- can an iframe escape from the CSS applied on top of it by its parent from a different domain?

Comment: Not that I know, no. Or at least it's supposed not to, by the SOP. The content of the iframe cannot put an overlay on the embedding page.